# Why is using cURL giving me a 403 forbidden error when file_get_contents works?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, file-get-contents

This is my PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.iphonehacks.com/2016/08/jailbreak-iphone-ipad-ios-9-3-3-pangu-1-1.html'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

The code above gives me a 403 error but when I use `file_get_contents`, I can echo the whole webpage.

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.iphonehacks.com/2016/08/jailbreak-iphone-ipad-ios-9-3-3-pangu-1-1.html');

echo $data;
```

Could anyone please point out what's wrong with the cURL method. I know I can use `file_get_contents` but I am interested in learning what went wrong in first case to get a better understanding of cURL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` option is incorrect. Change it to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36");
```

You shall not use the prefix "User-Agent: " on `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` option. The website was rejecting it because it was receiving the following request header:

> User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103
>   Safari/537.36

Instead of:

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Actually, no other site was giving any errors so I had no idea I was setting the user agent in a wrong way. I guess they did not care  about it.

Comment: the website is being stupid, it's probably trying to "combat spam" by blocking unknown user agent. which is really hard, practically impossible to do right, and very easy to do wrong, considering how many user agents are really out there;  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers